# Botão apagar numa ListView

Tags: visual-basic-6

Tenho um problema com o meu botão apagar, ou seja, ele funciona mas quando apago algo a partir do seu ID, este não apaga automaticamente. Tenho que reiniciar ou adicionar um novo registo para que este apague. Alguma sugestão?

Em baixo está o trecho do código e a interface do botão apagar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Isto esta ocorrento pois ao remover um item do banco de dados ele não será altomaticamente removido da array de items do ListView.

Se os items estiverem selecionados na ListView basta adicionar estas linhas no evento de click do botão remover:

```
    For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
    Next
```

Este codigo removerá automaticamente os items selecionados na ListView.

Outra maneira de fazer isto seria apagar todos os items da ListView e depois chamar a funcão que você utilizou para colocar todos os items na ListView.

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
ColocarItemsNaListView()
```